# Forgotten pgp passphrase - login to Docker

Tags: docker, pgp

Is there any way to make Docker abandon pgp authentication?

I've forgotten my passphrase and my key isn't on any key-server. I've tried to login using access token, but Docker still asks for pgp passphrase.

Can I do something other that brute-forcing my passphrase? I have access to my Docker email, login and password.

Comment: Not possible = see [pgp - Forgot OpenPGP key's passphrase, can I recover key or files somehow? - Information Security Stack Exchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/163514/forgot-openpgp-keys-passphrase-can-i-recover-key-or-files-somehow)

Comment: So what can I do? Change docker account? Change machine? I want to use docker

Comment: This is the first time I've heard of Docker using PGP authentication. What exactly are you doing that leads you to the PGP passphrase prompt? Are you talking about Docker the software, or do you mean the Docker *Hub* website?

Comment: When I use Docker CLI or Docker Desktop

Comment: From the article [Encrypted container images for container image security at rest](https://developer.ibm.com/articles/encrypted-container-images-for-container-image-security-at-rest/) I get the impression that you have encrypted your image (if it's yours), or that you are accessing a restricted image encrypted by its author. Which is your case?

Comment: I don't think so. I don't remember encrypting this image. Docker asks for OpenPGP passphrase when I just use command "docker login" - before I do anything related to images

Comment: I don't remember how I created this key and how I gave it to Docker

Answer (score 0):

I resolve it simply.
I can't access pgp file for docker and can't remember it.
So I found solution for it.
`docker login`
After docker login, it was disappeared and resolved.
Hope this will be help to you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

1. `gpg --generate-key`

It will be prompted to enter name, email and passphrase(remember this).
This will then generate a gpd-id public key.

2. initialise pass with the generated key.
   `pass init <your_generated_gpg-id_public_key>`

Next you will be asked passphrase for this key with which pass was initialized.

you can find it here in docker's official doc: https://docs.docker.com/desktop/get-started/#credentials-management-for-linux-users